# How can I implement method which would return me the same object but with the populated fields based on the provided list of the fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an object with some prepopulated fields:

```
Person = {
firstName: “John”,
lattName: “Silver”,
birthDater: ”male”,
hearColor:”green”
}
```

How can I implement a method thar would return me the same object but with the populated fields based on the provided list of the fields? I need retain fields in the object only that specified in criteria. E.g.:

```
person: Person = {
firstName: “John”,
lattName: “Silver”,
birthDater: ”male”,
hearColor:”green”
}

requiredFields: Array<string> = [“firstName”, “lattName”]

patialPerson: Person = createObjectequiredFieldsOnly(person, requiredFields: Array<string>)

private createObjectequiredFieldsOnly (person, requiredFields ): Person {
  return Person but with the field provided in requiredFields array, 
         all other fields are empty or not present in object at all.
}
```

Output:

```
patialyPopulatedPerson: Person {
firstName: “John”,
lattName: “Silver”
}
```

One thing that must be mentioned here is that the partialPerson could substitute the Person in further method calls, e.g I must be able to do:

```
proceedWithPerson(person);
proceedWithPerson(partialPerson);
```

Comment: https://docs-lodash.com/v4/pick/

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] suitable for pasting as-is into a standalone IDE so that people can get to work on your problem without first having to reproduce it.  Right now you have invalid syntax (open quotes and close quotes aren't valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [xdumaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381422/xdumaine) pointed out in a comment, you can use [`_.pick`](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/pick/) if you're using lodash. In plain JavaScript, you can use this code:

```js
const pick = (obj, fields) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(x => fields.includes(x[0])));

const Person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Silver',
  birthDater: 'male',
  hearColor: 'green',
};

const pickedPerson = pick(Person, ['firstName', 'lastName']);
console.log(pickedPerson);
```

It uses `.filter()` on the object's entries, then reconstructs the object from the filtered entries.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then you can mark it as correct. This will help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: Hello @Michael M. thanks for the answer. It solves the issue but with just small remark. in order to call a target method proceedWithPerson(person);  I had to cast pickedPerson to Person. So the final method call looks like  proceedWithPerson(pickedPerson as Person); P.S it looks like I don't use a lodash library in the project, so I'm working with plain javascript.